# How to deploy next js app on IIS with SSR benefit?

Tags: iis, next.js

I tried to deploy a next js app on IIS but I receive an error that say:
could not find .next folder!
People say that I have to export and deploy out folder but it doesn't has SSR benefits.
I'm a front-end guy. if you have a source for guide please send me. thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me what SSR benefits are? how did you deploy next js app on iis? Please post details of your error. about how to deploy next js app on iis you can refer to this link: [deploy next js on iis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y).

Comment: hey,
thank u this is work but I think that we should search for how to deploy Node JS server on IIS. the benefit of SSR is render the page on each request and this is so good for SEO. here is a article that explain the process of deploy Node JS app on IIS:
https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Comment: If you want something other than IISNode or ARR, you can try HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs Just see how clean the configuration is.